# Keras Image Classification Loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I am trying to make a simple CNN model which can recognize Pokemons. For the first try, I created by myself a very small dataset, composed of 100 pictures of 10 different Pokemons.
Using this code in Python, it seems like it is working well.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(200,200,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=400, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
test = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set= train.flow_from_directory('datasets/starter/train', target_size=(200,200), class_mode='categorical')
val_set= test.flow_from_directory('datasets/starter/test', target_size=(200,200), class_mode='categorical')

history=model.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch=32, epochs=3, validation_data=val_set, validation_steps=32)

test_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('datasets/starter/val/attempt.png', target_size=(200, 200))
test_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
result = model.predict(test_image)
print(training_set.class_indices)
print(result)

test_image2 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('datasets/starter/val/attempt2.png', target_size=(200, 200))
test_image2 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(test_image2)
test_image2 = np.expand_dims(test_image2, axis=0)
result2 = model.predict(test_image2)
print(training_set.class_indices)
print(result2)
```

The training accuracy at the last epoch is fixed at 1.
When I try to predict the example images:
attempt.png is a Charmander picture, its label is 1, so I am getting this vector: [[0. 1. 0. 0. ... 0.]]
attempt2.png is a Torchic picture, its label is 7, so I am getting: [[0. 0. ... 1. 0. 0. ]]

But I noticed that the loss in the 'model.compile' should be 'categorical_crossentropy' and not 'binary_crossentropy'. Using the categorical one, my program will not work anymore.
Can someone help me to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use Softmax as the last activation with categorical crossentropy as loss function

Comment: Thank you Cambala, it is working!! I do not know if you can help me, but another problem is that I get 1 of accuracy, but just 0.6 of validation accuracy. How can I solve it?

Comment: I think you should use much more images for model training. 10k at least

Comment: If the answer is working for you, I suggest you that to appriciate the contributor and have an accepted answer.

Further information is sigmoid is used for binary classifications. On the other hand, softmax gives the output of probability distributions over the classes. So, keep in mind that when you're doing a multiclass classifications, sigmoid activations won't work.